# npm WARN deprecated xxx: what should I do?

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs, warnings, lodash

I've been using grunt from a couple years now, and it's been like forever i've been seeing warnings like the following:

```
npm WARN deprecated win-spawn@2.0.0: use [cross-spawn](https://github.com/IndigoUnited/node-cross-spawn) or [cross-spawn-async](https://github.com/IndigoUnited/node-cross-spawn-async) instead.
npm WARN deprecated lodash@0.9.2: lodash@<2.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^3.0.0
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v6.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated lodash@2.2.1: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
```

my projects actually work anyway, even with these warnings. `lodash`is generally the one always giving me warnings, since day one.

here's the package.json file producing these errors:

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.2.3",
    "cssnano": "^3.4.0",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-browser-sync": "^1.5.3",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "^0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "~0.7.4",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.5.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.1",
    "grunt-critical": "^0.2.0",
    "grunt-delete-sync": "0.0.2",
    "grunt-newer": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-postcss": "^0.7.1",
    "grunt-processhtml": "^0.3.13"
  }
}
```

I guess some module or dependency is outdated but...

1) why is it still working? is it safe to ignore the warnings?
2) how do I know which module is outdated and what should i do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deprecated means it's not further developed, but also it won't change ever again. If a module relies on a deprecated package which has a bug the only way to solve is to upgrade the dependency. But as nothing changes it will work as it was working all the time.